# sending values from android to php without namepair value

Tags: php, android, post

I want to send data from android to php.Am using android api 23 and from android's developers site a got to know that namepairvalue is deprecated from api 22 and above. I referred to one of the post here in stackoverflow and got the below code. but still it doesn't work.

My problem is that am sending a value(ID) to php code and based on that value fetching the records from database. Now if i fetch data without using this value it works fine, but i am unable to send the id value to php code.

i am unable to find whats wrong in this code or may be my fault is editing the code. It would be great if someone helps me to understand it clearly .

Thank you in advance.

Here is the code snippet that i have tried.

Android Code:

```
String sid = staffid.toString(); // this sid is passed as intent from another activity and passing it to below link.
Log.d("SID :", "" + sid);
 try {
            URL url = null;
            url = new URL("http://usplhubli.96.lt/hrm/hrm_app/individual_view_staff.php");
            Log.d("url to display :", "" + url.toString());
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            // Log.d("os to display :", "" + os.toString());

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("sid", sid);
            Log.d("builder to display :", "" + builder.toString());


            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            Log.d("writer display :", "" + writer.toString());
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have this code in ***doInBackground(String... params)*** of ***AsyncTask*** 
based on this ***sid*** value i have to get the data from database and display it in android activity.

Here is the PHP code that i have tried

PHP Code:

```
$response=array();
$sid=$_POST["sid"];   // this is the POST data that am send from android
//$sid="4";     // this is the static value that i have tried and its working
print_r($sid);
include 'dbconfig.php';

$imagePath='http://www.usplhubli.96.lt/hrm';
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from hrm_staff where sid='$sid'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0) {
 $response["hrm_staff"] = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
 $recp = array();
 $recp["sid"]=$row["sid"];
 $fullName=$row['fname']."".$row['mname']."".$row['lname'];
 $recp["name"]= $fullName;
 $recp["address"]=$row['address'];
 $recp['city']=$row['city'];
 $recp["design"]=$row['did'];
 $recp["contact"]=$row['mobile'];
 $recp["email"]=$row['email'];
 $recp['qualification']=$row['quali'];
 $recp["dateofjoining"]=$row['doj'];
 $ppic1=$row['ppic'];
 $ppic1;
 $ppic21=$imagePath."/".trim($ppic1);
 $recp["ppic"]= $ppic21;
 array_push($response["hrm_staff"], $recp);

 }
  $response["success"] = 1;
 $response["message"]="display records";
 echo json_encode($response);   
 }
else
 {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: yes am checking.. i'll reply you. thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any problem or it is workable for you??

Comment: ya its working.. thank you so much. now i want to diaply each of the values   in different text boxes or store those values into different variables. how to do that. can you suggest something.?

Comment: For storing the value you can use the the sqlite or sharedpreference...Note these thing only use when you want to store the data for future perspective  like for saving the login and password.

Comment: ok then what do i do now..? i want to display these values into their textboxes in another activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95302/discussion-between-sagar-pawar-and-ravindra-kushwaha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use these lines of code for using **HttpURLConnection**

For sending the request parameter are as:-

```
  Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("phone", number)
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", password)
                    .appendQueryParameter("device_login",value);
```

And for the getting the request parameter in the post method of connectionUrl are as follow:-

```
URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)     url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000); ;
        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();


                System.out.println("REQUEST PARAMETERS ARE===" + query);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                urlConnection.connect();


                //Send request
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                        urlConnection.getOutputStream ());
                wr.writeBytes (query);
                wr.flush ();
                wr.close ();

                //Get Response
                InputStream isNew = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isNew));


                String line;
                response = new StringBuffer();
                while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);

                }
                rd.close();


                System.out.println("Final response===="+response);
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be more than one issue but a big one is you never send the request, all you are doing is creating the request and setting up the parameters

you need to do a

```
conn.connect();
```

or

```
conn.getInputStream();
```

or any number of things you can do to send the request and get the information you require

AFTER you write your params